# Change git branches into sub directories

Tags: bash, git

I have root folder with several sub folders with git branches. I use these commends to change git branches into every sub module:

```
alias gch='git checkout'
gchb() { gch $(gbr -r | grep "$1" | awk '{print substr(""$1"",8,length)}'); }
```

How I can execute this command into every sub directory?

Comment: What does the command `gbr -r` do?

Comment: @KamilCuk Probably an alias for `git branch -r`

Answer (score 1):

First, no need to use both `grep` and `awk` in this case:

```
gchb() { 
  gch $(gbr -r | awk '($0 ~ '"$1"'){print substr(""$1"",8,length)}'); 
}
```

The you could probably use something like:

```
for subdir in "${DIR}"/*; do
  [[ -d "${subdir}" ]] && gchb "${subdir}"
done
```

You probably could also use `find` with `-exec` option to do that kind of tasks, like this for example:

1) Define your alias and functions in a separate script (let's calling it `.gittutilsrc` for example) that can be load with `source`:

```
#!/bin/bash

alias gbr='git branch'
alias gch='git checkout'

gchb() { 
    gch $(gbr -r | awk '($0 ~ '"$1"'){print substr(""$1"",8,length)}'); 
}
```

2) Use it in find like this:

```
find "${DIR}" -type d -a -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c "source .gittutilsrc && gchb {}" \;
```

Note: `-mexdepth 1` is used in here to avoid recursivity in sub-sub-*-folders.

Comment: Is it possible to do it into one sh file, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I guess yes but avoiding to use aliases and functions. By the way, it's usually a good practice to define functions, constants, aliases, all stufs, that can be loaded with `source` and use as a library in multiple executables scripts (`.sh` files), in `.{your function's purpose summary}rc` files.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Otherwise you could choose the first solution with `for` and filenames expansion (see the globbing page of the [Advanced Bash scripting-guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) to get more details).